# How to make sure all Control are visible in the WhiteCanvas

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I did the following:

1. I create a BlankPage
2. Enlarge the White canvas by 66.67% so that I can see clearer where to position the control
3. I Drag button from toolBox, placing 4 button at each corner

   Problem:

a) Run the App with LocalMachine mode

3 buttons are not visible,

```
except this button.

 <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="193"/>
```

b) Run the App with Simulator mode

problem:

Only Top Left and Top Right are visible.

Bottom Left and Bottom Right not visible

Question :

Why all button placed within the White Canvas , not all are visible?

What Need to do? Below is the BlankPage, you can try and let me know what I did wrong.

Appreciate your help.

```
<Page
    x:Class="w10QMgmt.BlankPage3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:w10QMgmt"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1201,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="151"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="193"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1139,832,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="183"/>
        <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,844,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="143"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you have put all your buttons inside Grid control, there is no Canvas used

2) you have set all your button positions based on their Margin's - by placing them by your mouse - don't ever do it unsless you know what you are doing and what generated code means

3) changing window/page size does not affect the buttons positions - because their position is based on margins - distance from the left and top - it will never be changed in this scenario

to do it properly (if you want to have 4 buttons placed in four corners of the windows) just remove the margins - and set Horizontal and Vertical Aligment to proper corners:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="151"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="193"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="88" Width="183"/>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="52" Width="143"/>
</Grid>
```

now their positions will be updated when the window/page size changes - because the Grid size will be changed, and all it's children positions inside will be updated - because the positions are now set relatively

Comment: I Dont really understand the UWP Approach for UI Design. The White Rect is the GRID. Pls help. How to place a control ANYWHERE in the GRID base on the position I want ? When I drag any control from ToolBox onto the Grid, it will automatically have margin.

Comment: just read some tutorial... in Grid you can place the control by setting it's Horizontal/Vertical Aligment to have it keeping the right edge, you can create colums and rows and then place the control in the row/col you want. If you want to have your control always in the same position - use Canvas and set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties - but remember to update them when the window/page size changes. Your problem is that you are placing button on 1201 pixel, then run the app which window has less than 1201 pixels width and you wonder why it is not visible?

Comment: I think it is hard to find  tutorial on Win10 UI design. But I think i figure out after a few tries on your advice-- use the html approach Row and Column. What u mean update the windows/Page size changes? Now I am using Rows and Columns to position the control. pls elaborate.

Comment: when you use designer in Visual Studio it is displaying your view with some width and heigth (you can set it using DesignWidth and DesignHeight), when you run your app on device - the window size is full screen (with the width and height depending on the device) or is in windowed state - and you can change it's width and height as you want. If you can't find tutorial for windows 10 - search tutorials for win rt/win 8/wpf/silverlight - int the matter of simple containter controls (grid, canvas, stackpanel etc.) they will be 90% the same. You need to learn how they position their content.

Comment: Finally, I use the Row and Column approach to display controls. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For myself i'am keen on the RelativePanel, only use the Margins for small pushing and Pulling.

```
<Grid>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Name="1"
                RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>
        <Button Name="2"
                RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
        <Button Name="3"
                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>
        <Button Name="4"
                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

Also what @RTdev says, please pick up some tutorial, UWP for win 10 is a great start for layout and how to use It.